# How to add a property to a series of objects nested within an array?

Tags: javascript

From the call to an api endpoint, I get the following array of nested objects, which is a directory tree

```
const tree = [
  {
    label: "OTHER",
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "PARENT/",
    children: [
      {
        label: "strat   end/",
        children: [
          {
            label: "startEnd",
            children: [
              {
                label: "Inner1",
                children: [
                  {
                    label: "Inner2",
                    children: [
                      {
                        label: "Inner3",
                        children: [],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I also have this list of tokens

```
const tokens = [
  'PARENT',
  'strat   end',
  'startEnd',
  'Inner1',
  'Inner2',
  'Inner3',
  'Inner4'
]
```

I need to add the expanded property with the value true in objects within the label property coined with each one in the tokens list

The expected result should be as follows

Thank you for your advices

```
const expectedTree = [
  {
    label: "OTHER",
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: "PARENT/",
    expaned: true,
    children: [
      {
        label: "strat   end/",
        expaned: true,
        children: [
          {
            label: "startEnd",
            expaned: true,
            children: [
              {
                label: "Inner1",
                expaned: true,
                children: [
                  {
                    label: "Inner2",
                    expaned: true,
                    children: [
                      {
                        label: "Inner3",
                        expaned: true,
                        children: [],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Walk the tree recursively. At each step, check if `tokens.includes(current.label)` and then add the property.

Comment: Is the `/` within `"strat   end/"` intentional? Because it is not present within `tokens`. It looks like a typo, either within `tree` where it should not be present or within `tokens` where it should be present.

Comment: It's a typo, thanks for highligh it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `reduce` method on tokens and then `find` to get object on every level that matches the label.

```js
const tree = [{"label":"OTHER","children":[]},{"label":"PARENT/","children":[{"label":"strat   end/","children":[{"label":"startEnd","children":[{"label":"Inner1","children":[{"label":"Inner2","children":[{"label":"Inner3","children":[]}]}]}]}]}]}]
const tokens = ["PARENT","strat   end","startEnd","Inner1","Inner2","Inner3","Inner4"]

tokens.reduce((r, e) => {
  const o = r.find(({label}) => label.startsWith(e));

  if (o) {
    o.expanded = true;
    return o.children
  }

  return r
}, tree);

console.log(tree)
```

Comment: Pretty nice solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

```
const tokens = [
  'PARENT',
  'strat   end',
  'startEnd',
  'Inner1',
  'Inner2',
  'Inner3',
  'Inner4'
]
```

Is a path pointing to the deepest node that is expanded and you do not mind mutating the original data structure you could do:

```
let nodes = tree;
for (const token of tokens) {
  const node = nodes.find(node => node.label == token);
  node.expaned = true;
  nodes = node.children;
}
```

Like I already said, this does mutate the original structure. However depending on your scenario this might no be an issue.

Comment: Indeed, mutation is not a problem right now